# Using Node.js iterating array of object and if value matched then insert all related values in different array

Tags: node.js

INPUT

```
[
{"Id":1,"text":"Welcome","question":"san","translation":"willkommen."}, 
{"Id":1,"text":"Welcome","question":"se","translation":"bienvenida"}, 
{"Id":1,"text":"Welcome","question":"fr","translation":"propriétaires"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ajax","question":"san","translation":"ommen."}, 
{"Id":1,"text":"ajax","question":"se","translation":"bienve"}, 
{"Id":1,"text":"ajax","question":"fr","translation":"propires"}
]
```

if question = san then all "san" objects will be inserted in array like and so on-

```
san:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"san","translation":"willkommen.}, 
     {"text":"ajax","question":"san","translation":"ommen."}, 

se:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"se","translation":"bienvenida.}, 
    {"text":"ajax","question":"se","translation":"bienve."}, 

fr:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"fr","translation":"propriétaires.}, 
    {"text":"ajax","question":"fr","translation":"propires."},
```

Question is how do i check if question=san then make one array and insert all san values in it and so on without hardcoding the question property values.

Tried looping things but how to match without hardcoding because in future question attribute  can change .
question="san" will be all together in an array "se" will be all together in an array and so on.
New to this not know much about nodejs.

Tried something like this but not coming as required way

```
fs.readFile('./data.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
data = JSON.parse(data); 

var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var lang = data[i].language;
for(var j= 0; j< data.length; j++) {
  if(lang == data[j].language){
    array.push(data[j].language);
    array.push(data[j].translation);
    array.push(data[j].text);
   }   
 }
}
```

output Required

```
san:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"san","translation":"willkommen.}, 
     {"text":"ajax","question":"san","translation":"ommen."}, 

se:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"se","translation":"bienvenida.}, 
    {"text":"ajax","question":"se","translation":"bienve."}, 

fr:[{"text":"Welcome","question":"fr","translation":"propriétaires.}, 
    {"text":"ajax","question":"fr","translation":"propires."},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use ES6 functions instead of `for`. You can separate the different processes and make the code more modular and declarative. This way you can change easily the desired output since your code is made by little pieces.

```js
const data = [
 {"Id":1,"text":"hi all present ","language":"sde","translation":"Hernjd ndjjsjdj"},
 {"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"ses","translation":"dfks kdfk kdfk"},
{"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"sfr","translation":"bsh kkoweofeo"},
{"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"szh","translation":"kdijo keow"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"sde","translation":"Konto eid ke"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"ses","translation":"La cueweffewfefwef."},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"sfr","translation":"Cowefrwef"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"szh","translation":"fhewjhfwh"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"sde","translation":"Ihr fwejiewf"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"ses","translation":"Ya hfuwifrw"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"sfr","translation":"Votrkwfwe"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"szh","translation":"dmksfkwkf"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"sde","translation":"AKTION"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"ses","translation":"ACCIONES"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"fr","translation":"ACTION"}];

// Define the properties that we want to filter for each element
const filterProperties = (item) => ({
 text:item.text,
  language: item.language,
  translation:item.translation
})

// Given a type of languages ('sde'), filter the data in function of this value
const getItemsByLanguage = (language) => {
 return data.filter((item) => item.language === language)
}

const onlyUnique = (value, index, self) => { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// Get the unique values of languages: ['sde', 'ses', 'sfr', ...]
const uniqueLanguages = data.map((item) => item.language).filter(onlyUnique)

// Get all found items for a language ('sde') and get the desired format (returns array of objects)
const resultArray = uniqueLanguages.map((language) => ( 
 {[language]: getItemsByLanguage(language).map(filterProperties)}
 ))
 
 // Convert the array of objects to single object
 const result = Object.assign({}, ...resultArray)
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Tried this with large json and running on cmd its giving me wrong answer

Comment: Works well for the example. There might be more cases that are not included in the example. In that case, I cannot do anything else without more info.

Comment: Can u check with my snippet code take that data and try because i am also not sure why for that your code is not working and thanks for you code.

Comment: The second example data is different from the first you provided

Comment: thanks for spending time Rashomon its working like a charm thanks thanks... but u had change its difficult for me understand as i new in node js and es6 too.can u explain more briefly.

Comment: All the code is described in the snippet. Basically I would study `map` and `filter` ES6 functions. Only them are necessary to solve the problem. The main concept is to divide the big problem in little steps. Then we can combine them to get the final result. Tell me if you have any specific dubt

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
 {"Id":1,"text":"hi all present ","language":"sde","translation":"Hernjd ndjjs 
 jdj"},
 {"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"ses","translation":"dfks kdfk 
 kdfk"},
{"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"sfr","translation":"bsh kkowe 
ofeo"},
{"Id":1,"text":"hi all present","language":"szh","translation":"kdijo keow"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"sde","translation":"Konto eid ke"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"ses","translation":"La cueweffewfef 
wef."},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"sfr","translation":"Cowefrwef"},
{"Id":1,"text":"activated","language":"szh","translation":"fhewjhfwh"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"sde","translation":"Ihr fwejiewf"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"ses","translation":"Ya hfuwifrw"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"sfr","translation":"Votrkwfwe"},
{"Id":1,"text":"completed","language":"szh","translation":"dmksfkwkf"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"sde","translation":"AKTION"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"ses","translation":"ACCIONES"},
{"Id":1,"text":"ACTION","language":"fr","translation":"ACTION"}];


// Define the properties that we want to filter for each element
const filterProperties = (data) => ({
 text:data.text,
  question: data.question,
  translation:data.translation
})

// Given a type of question ('san'), filter the data in function of this value
const getQuestions = (question) => {
 return data.filter((item) => item.question === question)
}

const onlyUnique = (value, index, self) => { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// Get the unique values of questions: ['san', 'se', 'fr']
const uniqueQuestions = data.map((item) => item.question).filter(onlyUnique)

// Get all found values for a question and get the desired format (returns 
 array of objects)
const resultArray = uniqueQuestions.map((question) => ( 
 {[question]: getQuestions(question).map(filterProperties)}
 ))
 
 // Convert the array of objects to single object
 const result = Object.assign({}, ...resultArray)
 
 console.log(result)
```